# \addcontentsline misplaced in ToC when followed by \include

Tags: table-of-contents, include

I seem to have hit a bug in LaTeX concerning the table of contents. Apparently, if a `\addcontentsline` is followed by an `\include`, all the headers in the included file are printed in the table of contents before the one specified by the `\addcontentsline`.

Here is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Hello}

\part*{Unnumbered part}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Unnumbered part}

% \chapter{How do you do?}
% The bug disappears if I uncomment the line above.

\include{bug_include}
% This include starts with a \chapter command. The rest of the file is irrelevant. 

\end{document}
```

The file `bug_include.tex` starts with a `\chapter` command, say `\chapter{Goodbye}` and may contain other header commands (`\section`, etc.)

What I obtain, after compiling twice, is a table of contents with

```
1. Hello
2. Goodbye
   2.1 A section in bug_include
Unnumbered part
```

while I should have obtained

```
1. Hello
Unnumbered part
2. Goodbye
   2.1 A section in bug_include
```

Note that the `\include` seems to be an important part of the bug. If the main file contains regular section commands after the `\addcontentsline`, the bug does not occur.

I can hide the bug by putting the `\addcontentsline` before the `\part*` command. But as I am also usually using the `hyperref` package, my actual work-around to have correct links is in fact:

```latex
\cleardoublepage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Unnumbered part}
\part*{Unnumbered part}
```

I am seeing this bug with texlive 2001 as packaged by fedora 37 and with texlive 2022 as packaged by fedora 38.

Am I overlooking something? Is it a well-known bug? Should I report it somewhere?

Nota: the bug is probably the same as the one reported in question [485320](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485320/toc-entry-misplaced-with-addcontentsline), but that other question does not have a MWE, so it is hard to say.

Comment: \addcontentsline after \part is wrong: if you add normal text and test you can see that it points to the wrong page number 4 and not 3.

Comment: `\include` uses `\immediate\write` to switch to the `aux` file of the included file. But `\addcontentsline` uses `\write` and therefore writes the entry to the aux file, when the next page will be output. So the `\input` for the sub-aux-file comes before the ToC entry. This is a known problem of `\addcontentsline` in the main file. In your case, you should move it before the `\part*` and add a `\cleardoublepage` before it. Another suggestion would be to use a class like `scrreprt`, which provides `\addpart` for not numbered parts with ToC entry.